# using data.table to filter

Tags: r, data.table

I have this dataset (example):

```
dt <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5),
                 diagnosis = c("cancer", "cancer", "cancer", "cancer", "cancer", "cancer", "cancer", "cancer", "cancer", "cancer"),
                 Date = c(2008,2001,2013,2008,2013,2013,2013,2001,2002,2013))
```

I ONLY want patients with a first diagnosis in 2013. So any other year should be out of the dataset.

However a patient should not be counted in the new dataset if the patients has a diagnosis in 2008.
If the patient hav had a diagnosis before 2008, then we wil keep them, with their 2013 diagnosis.

So the final dataset will look like this:

```
 ID diagnosis Date
3  cancer    2013
4  cancer    2013
5  cancer    2013
```

How can I do so by using `data.table`

Comment: Not clear what you need to do

Comment: dont understand. why is there no ID1 anymore?
Also, please share your example data in a ready to use format, e.g. with `dput()`

Comment: Because if you have a diagnosis in 2008 and 2013 you cant not be in the final data. only if you have a diagnosis in 2013 alone or before 2008 and 2013 - makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

Updated code:

```
dt <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5),
                 diagnosis = c("cancer", "cancer", "cancer", "cancer", "cancer", "cancer", "cancer", "cancer", "cancer", "cancer"),
                 Date = c(2008,2001,2013,2008,2013,2013,2013,2001,2002,2013))

dt[diagnosis=="cancer" & Date == 2013 & !(ID %in% dt[diagnosis=="cancer" & Date == 2008, ID]),]
```

Output:

```
   ID diagnosis Date
1:  3    cancer 2013
2:  4    cancer 2013
3:  5    cancer 2013
```

Comment: Thank you - but not really - I have editet my question :)

Comment: Please see the code, I have updated it @Hellihansen

Answer (score 1):

Using a not-join (see `?data.table`):

```r
dt[Date == 2013][!dt[Date == 2008], on=.(ID)]
```

Output

```
      ID diagnosis  Date
   <num>    <char> <num>
1:     3    cancer  2013
2:     4    cancer  2013
3:     5    cancer  2013
```

I guess this it's more efficient to use a filter than an aggregate condition like `any`.

Answer (score 0):

```
dt[, .SD[!2008 %in% unlist(.SD) & Date == 2013], ID]
```

or probably a bit better after seeing Waldi's answer and do:

```
dt[, .SD[!any(Date == 2008) & Date == 2013], ID]
```

**results**

```
# ID diagnosis Date
# 1:  3    cancer 2013
# 2:  4    cancer 2013
# 3:  5    cancer 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
dt[, .SD[Date == 2013 & !any(between(Date, 2008, 2012)),], ID]
#       ID diagnosis  Date
#    <num>    <char> <num>
# 1:     3    cancer  2013
# 2:     4    cancer  2013
# 3:     5    cancer  2013
```